# C++のios_baseが公開されていないといわれる

Tags: c++

コンソールAPPを途中まで作り、ビルドできるかためしたところ、下記のようなエラーが残ったのですが、意味がよくわかりません。

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ios:42:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/istream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream:38,
                 from stdafx.h:11,
                 from OperationService.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h: コピーコンストラクタ ‘std::basic_ios::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios&)’ 内:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:786:5: エラー: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ は非公開です
     ios_base(const ios_base&);
     ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/istream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream:38,
                 from stdafx.h:11,
                 from OperationService.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: エラー: within this context
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^
In file included from stdafx.h:11:0,
                 from OperationService.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream: コピーコンストラクタ ‘std::basic_stringstream::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream&)’ 内:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream:502:11: 備考: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios&)’ first required here
     class basic_stringstream : public basic_iostream
           ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ios:43:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/istream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream:38,
                 from stdafx.h:11,
                 from OperationService.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/streambuf: コピーコンストラクタ ‘std::basic_stringbuf::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf&)’ 内:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/streambuf:802:7: エラー: ‘std::basic_streambuf::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]’ は非公開です
       basic_streambuf(const basic_streambuf& __sb)
       ^
In file included from stdafx.h:11:0,
                 from OperationService.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream:64:11: エラー: within this context
     class basic_stringbuf : public basic_streambuf
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream: コピーコンストラクタ ‘std::basic_stringstream::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream&)’ 内:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/sstream:502:11: 備考: synthesized method ‘std::basic_stringbuf::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf&)’ first required here
     class basic_stringstream : public basic_iostream
           ^
OperationService.cpp: メンバ関数 ‘std::stringstream OperationService::createJA()’ 内:
OperationService.cpp:39:9: 備考: synthesized method ‘std::basic_stringstream::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream&)’ first required here
  return ss;
         ^
```

C++開発は2度目(以前もコンソールアプリケーションを作成しました。)
ほとんど実装は以前のものの流用ですが、以前はビルドできました。

ios_baseが公開されていないとのことなので、fstreamの部分が悪いのかと思い、いろいろいじってみましたがうまくいきません。

以下、おそらくエラーの該当クラスです。

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "OperationService.h"
#include "DomParser.h"

using namespace std;

#define ASSERT_JA "~/.base_ja"
#define ASSERT_EN "~/.base_en"

#define MIGR_JA "~/.mig_ja"
#define MIGR_EN "~/.mig_en"

/**
* Migrationの英語版
**/
stringstream OperationService::createEN() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss <<  略
    ss << "Before January 8th, 2014" << endl;
    return ss;
}

/**
* Migrationの日本語版
**/
stringstream OperationService::createJA() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << 略
    ss << "1.0が破棄されると、XMPPサービスおよびAPIは利用できなくなります。" << endl;
    return ss;
}

/**
 * diff
 **/
void OperationService::diff() {

    cout << "====================== diffedence check start =========================" << endl;

    fstream ifs;
    DomParser domParser;

    // 日本語正規ドキュメント作成
    ifs.open(ASSERT_JA, ios::in);
    if (!ifs) {
            ifs.close();
            ifs.open(ASSERT_JA, ios::out);
            ifs << createJA().str() << endl;
            ifs.close();
    }

    // 英語正規ドキュメント作成
    ifs.open(ASSERT_EN, ios::in);
    if (!ifs) {
            ifs.close();
            ifs.open(ASSERT_EN, ios::out);
            ifs << createEN().str() << endl;
            ifs.close();
    }

    stringstream ss;

    // 英語HTML取得
    ss << "wget https://dummy/migrations -O " << MIGR_EN << endl;
    system(ss.str().c_str());
    ss.clear();

    // 日本語HTML取得
    ss << "wget https://dummy/migrations?locale=ja_JP -O " << MIGR_JA << endl;
    system(ss.str().c_str());
    ss.clear();

    // 日本語MigrationTEXT抽出
    {
            xmlDocPtr doc = domParser.parse(MIGR_JA);
            xmlNodeSetPtr nodeSet = domParser.executeXpath(doc, (xmlChar *)"//./text()");
            string content = (char*)xmlXPathNodeSetItem(nodeSet, 0)->content;
            ifs.open(MIGR_JA, ios::out | ios::trunc);
            ifs << content << endl;
            ifs.close();
    }

    // 英語MigrationTEXT抽出
    {
            xmlDocPtr doc = domParser.parse(MIGR_EN);
            xmlNodeSetPtr nodeSet = domParser.executeXpath(doc, (xmlChar *)"//./text()");
            string content = (char*)xmlXPathNodeSetItem(nodeSet, 0)->content;
            ifs.open(MIGR_EN, ios::out | ios::trunc);
            ifs << content << endl;
            ifs.close();
    }

    // 比較実行 日本語
    cout << "--------- Japanese ----------" << endl << endl << endl;
    ss << "diff -Bt " << ASSERT_JA << " " << MIGR_JA;
    system(ss.str().c_str());
    ss.clear();

    // 比較実行 英語
    cout << "--------- English ----------" << endl << endl << endl;
    ss << "diff -Bt " << ASSERT_EN << " " << MIGR_EN;
    system(ss.str().c_str());
    ss.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Return stringstream from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119963/return-stringstream-from-a-function) などを読みますと、C++ では stream オブジェクトをコピーすることができない様ですね。

リンク先にも書いてある様に、`return ss.str()` として `std::string` を返す様にすると良いかと思います。

**※ yoh2 さんのご指摘を受けて以下を削除します。**


<strike>以下の様にして stringstream オブジェクトへのポインタを返す様にすれば良いかと思います。</strike>

```
stringstream* OperationService::createEN() {
  stringstream* ss = new(stringstream);
  *ss <<  略
  *ss << "Before January 8th, 2014" << endl;
  return ss;
}
                :     

ifs << createEN()->str() << endl;
```

Comment: 後者はメモリリークを引き起こしますので、、前者の、`std::string` を返すようにして `return ss.str()` を返すやり方がよさげです。他にも、 `std::unique_ptr<std::stringstream>` あたりを返す手もないわけではありませんけど、使用場面を見ると、`std::string` さえあればよさそうに思えます。

Comment: @yoh2 ありがとうございます、メモリリークについては考えが及びませんでした。。。この回答を削除したいのですが、よろしいですか？

Comment: `new stringstream` する部分の回答を削除する編集で十分だと思いますよ。参考リンクもしっかりしていますし、消すのは惜しいです。

Answer (score 2):

`stringstream`はコピー不可能なオブジェクトのため、C++03までは関数の戻り値型を`stringstream`とするのはおすすめしません。

C++11以降では、`stringstream`がムーブ可能なオブジェクトに拡張されたため、そのままのコードでもコンパイルできると思います。

```
// C++11以降
stringstream some_function() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << ...;
    return ss;  // (暗黙に)ムーブで関数戻り値を返す
}
```

---

> OperationService.cpp: メンバ関数 ‘std::stringstream OperationService::createJA()’ 内:
>   OperationService.cpp:39:9: 備考: synthesized method ‘std::basic_stringstream::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream&)’ first required here
>     return ss;

エラーメッセージの末尾付近に直接的な原因箇所：メンバ関数`OperationService::createJA()`の`return ss;`に問題があることが示されています。

「ios_baseで非公開が云々」という理解しづらいエラーメッセージになる理由は、次の通りです。

- オブジェクトをコピーするときは、対象クラス(`stringstream`)のコピーコンストラクタが呼ばれる。
- コピーコンストラクタでは、全ての基底クラス(`ios_base`, `ios`, `istream`, `ostream`, `iostream`)のコピーコンストラクタを呼び出す。
- 全てのコピーコンストラクタは、クラスの外からアクセス可能(`public`)でなければいけない。
- C++03では「コピー不可能なクラス」を表現する方法として、「コピーコンストラクタを非公開(`private`)にしておく」しか手段がなかった。
- コピー不可能クラスのオブジェクトを、ユーザコードが誤ってコピー操作すると「基底クラスのコピーコンストラクタが非公開」という一見すると謎なコンパイルエラーになる。

Comment: 手元のCygwinにインストールしているGCC 4.9.3（というかlibstdc++）では、<sstream>がまだC++11に対応できていないようでムーブできません。（最新のlibstdc++ではC++11に対応しているようです。）

Comment: GCC/libstdc++は5.x系以降でないとダメそうですね… Clang/libc++では記載の通りに動くみたいです。 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hBBM2eyTQThacX2P